# GRE Mathematics Multivariable Calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, gre-exam

I'm studying for the GRE subject test on 4/5, and I've been going through the princeton review book, which seems to be the canonical guide. In the multivariable section the theorems are pretty basic, they only mention green's theorem, and omit Stokes, Gausses Theorem, Surface integrals, if not more. Is this because these theorems are not tested on the subject test?

In that vein does anybody know of a more comprehensive list of topics other than what is on the ets site?

Thanks.

Comment: I speak from the perspective of ancient history, but when I took the GRE in 1974 there was a question on Stokes's Theorem, even with differential forms notation. I believe my students tell me that Stokes's Theorem has shown up in recent times.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You should study a bit of topology, ODE, number theory ( chinese remainder theorem, etc..)

Comment: I've studied these things extensively in school, (except for ODE) which is why I'm more concerned with the multivariable calculus section. Can anybody else speak to my question?